# Polymer core-list inside core-pages

Tags: css, html, polymer

I just startet a polymer project to build a web application. On this site I use `<core-pages>` to navigate between different content. Inside one page is a `<core-list>` that is going to be master-detail view. But this `<core-list>` is empty because the viewport has a height of 0. May anybody tell me how to fix that?

Here is the Code of this area:

```
<body fit >
<template is="auto-binding">
<core-drawer-panel>

  <core-header-panel drawer>
    <core-toolbar id="navheader'">
      <span>Menü</span>
    </core-toolbar>
    <core-menu id="drawerMenu" selected="modules" selectedIndex="{{route}}" 
            valueattr="hash" excludedLocalNames="hr">
        <core-item icon="label" hash="modules">Module</core-item>
        <core-item icon="question-answer" hash="credits">Über uns</core-item></div>
        <hr>
        <core-item icon="receipt" hash="impressum">Impressum</core-item>
        <core-item icon="receipt" hash="privace_policy">Datenschutzerklärung</core-item>
    </core-menu>
   </core-header-panel>

  <core-header-panel main>
    <core-toolbar id="mainheader">
      <paper-icon-button 
        id="navicon" icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
      <span flex>Gruppenstunde</span>
    </core-toolbar>
    <core-pages selected="{{route}}" valueattr="hash" layout>
        <div><modules-list hash="modules"></modules-list></div>
        <div><page-credits hash="credits"></page-credits></div>
        <div><page-impressum hash="impressum"></page-impressum></div>
        <div><page-privacy-policy hash="privace_policy"></page-privacy-policy></div>
    </core-pages>    
  </core-header-panel>

</core-drawer-panel>
</template>
<script>
    var template = document.querySelector('template');
    template.addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
        var navicon = document.getElementById('navicon');
        var drawerPanel = document.querySelector('core-drawer-panel');
        navicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
            drawerPanel.togglePanel();
        });
        var menu = document.querySelector('core-menu');
        menu.addEventListener('core-activate', function() {
            drawerPanel.togglePanel();
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
```

Inside the `<modules-list>` is the `core-list`:

```
<paper-shadow z="1"></paper-shadow>
<paper-fab icon="list" class="filter"></paper-fab>
<paper-fab icon="add" class="add"></paper-fab>
<core-ajax url="../includes/api/polymerGetModules.php" response="{{data}}" handleAs="json" auto></core-ajax>
<core-list data="{{filteredData}}" extraItems="50" on-core-activate="{{moduleSelected}}" selection="{{selection}}" flex>
    <template>
        <div class="list-item {{selected?'selected':''}}">
            <h2>{{model.title}}</h2>
        </div>
    </template>
</core-list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the layout attribute `fit` to your `<core-pages>` element. This will absolutely position your element filling up it's first positioned parent.

Comment: That works great, but in that case the scroll-bar is inside the page and not on the right. Have a look on this page, where I adopted your changes: http://www.test.gruppenstunde.eu/stack2.php Any idea how to change that?

Comment: That's your own code, the `max-width` and `width:90%` on the same element.

Comment: That's what I don't whant to change. Is there any chance to position the scrollbar on the browsers border?

Comment: @Jokus Ehm, that's like saying: I want this background blue, but I don't want to change the `background-color:red` property. If you want to have the scrollbar right and the content in a narrow view you will have to add another element *in* the current which restricts the width, not restrict the parent width.